# AddTransient<IService, Service>() versus AddTransient<Service>()

Tags: c#

I am learning the built-in DI of .net core and I am confused why I can use `B` but not `A` in the following?

```
interface IService
{
    void Do();
}

class Service : IService
{
    public void Do() => Console.WriteLine("Doing...");
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (ServiceProvider sp = RegisterServices())
        {
            sp.GetRequiredService<Service>().Do();
        }
    }

    static ServiceProvider RegisterServices()
    {
        ServiceCollection sc = new ServiceCollection();
        //sc.AddTransient<IService, Service>(); // A
        sc.AddTransient<Service>(); // B
        return sc.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
sc.AddTransient<Service>();
```

You're telling the `ServiceProvider` (container) that it must be able to resolve `Service`. When I ask for `Service`, give me `Service`.

That would work if you had a class that depended *directly* on `Service`. For example:

```
public class DependsOnService
{
    private readonly Service _service;

    public DependsOnService(Service service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

But in many (perhaps most cases) we're going to write classes to depend on abstractions (like interfaces) instead of directly on concrete classes. So the above would more commonly look like this:

```
public class DependsOnService
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public DependsOnService(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

Now, when `DependsOnService` is created, the container must resolve `IService`. It has to know that when it's asked to resolve `IService`, the implementation it should create is `Service`. That's what this does:

```
sc.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
```

It says, when I ask for `IService`, give me `Service`.